# How to print the last value of each subarray (Numpy)

Tags: arrays, python-3.x, numpy, list-comprehension

I have managed to create a comprehensivised list in the above array, however, I am not able to print out *only the last element of each subarray* without creating a new for loop.
Could someone explain how to combine the two loops, please?

```
import numpy as np

b = np.array([[[0.55867166, 0.06210792, 0.08147297],
        [0.82579068, 0.91512478, 0.06833034]],

       [[0.05440634, 0.65857693, 0.30296619],
        [0.06769833, 0.96031863, 0.51293743]],

       [[0.09143215, 0.71893382, 0.45850679],
        [0.58256464, 0.59005654, 0.56266457]],

       [[0.71600294, 0.87392666, 0.11434044],
        [0.8694668 , 0.65669313, 0.10708681]],

       [[0.07529684, 0.46470767, 0.47984544],
        [0.65368638, 0.14901286, 0.23760688]]])

list5 = [[[e for e in r if e <= 0.5] for r in s] for s in b]
print(list5)
for i in list5:
    print((i[-1]))
```

Comment: do you mean the last elements of the lists in `list5`?

Comment: my goal is to get the last value in each subarray from _b_

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should show the results of this code!  Most of us can't run the code menttally (or are too lazy to do so).

```
In [46]: b.shape
Out[46]: (5, 2, 3)
In [47]: list5 = [[[e for e in r if e <= 0.5] for r in s] for s in b]
In [48]: list5
Out[48]: 
[[[0.06210792, 0.08147297], [0.06833034]],
 [[0.05440634, 0.30296619], [0.06769833]],
 [[0.09143215, 0.45850679], []],
 [[0.11434044], [0.10708681]],
 [[0.07529684, 0.46470767, 0.47984544], [0.14901286, 0.23760688]]]
In [49]: for i in list5:
    ...:     print((i[-1]))
    ...: 
[0.06833034]
[0.06769833]
[]
[0.10708681]
[0.14901286, 0.23760688]
```

The result has lists with different lengths - 0,1,2.  That suggests it isn't worth trying to eleminate loops. Or at least it will require some lateral thinking to get around that.

I can replace the inner most iteration

```
In [52]: list6 = [[r[r<=0.5] for r in s][-1] for s in b]
In [53]: list6
Out[53]: 
[array([0.06833034]),
 array([0.06769833]),
 array([], dtype=float64),
 array([0.10708681]),
 array([0.14901286, 0.23760688])]
```

And since you only want the last sublist from the middle dimension:

```
In [54]: [r[r<=0.5] for r in b[:,-1,:]]
Out[54]: 
[array([0.06833034]),
 array([0.06769833]),
 array([], dtype=float64),
 array([0.10708681]),
 array([0.14901286, 0.23760688])]
```

Comment: well that beats my solution `r =[r[r<=0.5] for r in np.array([[sub_sub[-1] for sub_sub in sub] for sub in b]).flatten()]`